# Uploading of a picture in c#

Tags: c#, image

I faced with a problem thumbing through the old book. It suggestes:

```
protected override void DoPage(Graphics g, Color cl, int cx, int cy)
 {
   Image i = Image.FromFile("dsds.png");
   i.DrawImage(image,90,0);
 }
```

The question is how to upload the picture? I`m noob, so pls write your code using novel facilities. TY

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-render-images-with-gdi can someone clarify that

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `g.Drawimage(i, ...); ???` - So, what do you mean by uploading? Did you try anything? Research?

Comment: _can someone clarify that_ Not here surly. There is a russian SO site, though..

Comment: u can highlight the text and it`ll be translated

Comment: I`m actually LF simple way of uploading

Comment: Thanks but no thanks. If you want help, do find us the english version, please! And then ask specific questions!

Comment: Ok, for sure i will search

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-render-images-with-gdi

Comment: Ok, thanks. But what is unclear? With the two corrections from my 1st comment you should have an image with a second image painted over it. This has nothing to do with uploading. [googling your question title](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+Uploading+of+a+picture+in+c%23&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b) brings up many promising links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Image` by itself cannot be drawn through `DrawImage`. To use `DrawImage` you also need a `graphics` object.

```
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics;  // or any other container
```

Now you can draw an image,

```
g.DrawImage(i, 90, 0);
```

Comment: He actually has a Graphics g in his paramteres. No idea what it is..

Comment: Ty very much. I`m curious if DoPage still exist? I mean i`ve seen that only in obsolete documentary

Comment: I doubt it has ever existed outside of your book.

Comment: I`ve searched some examples in the Internet so

Comment: Book has been wroten by Charles Petzold

Comment: quote _...by putting the graphics output code in a separate method named DoPage that is called by..._  So: as I guessed, `DoPage` is just a method he wrote, passing in some Graphics object; could be from a Paint or PrintPage event or from another source. (You have introduced a typo or two..) Petzold is still worth reading.